# How to ping two VMs running on different Host.?

Tags: networking, fedora

I have two physical machine A and B (Fedora 22 everywhere). 
VM 'a' is running on host 'A'. VM 'b' is running on host 'B'. 
I want to ping VM 'a' from VM 'b' and vice-versa.

Comment: How do you setup network interface ?

Comment: i didn't setup any network yet.

Comment: Then you should start with "How do I configure network on a VM?". Once this is solved/done, you may tackle the VM to VM issue. [Here](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections)'s a doc about network bridge on Debian.

Comment: also you need to configure the network on the host operating system / hypervisor

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up bridged network adapters in each of the vms, so they get physical access to the network.

Be sure to generate a unique mac-address on each of the vms adapters.

Then you logon as root (or do su/sudo) on each vm and add network a address in the "vm-subnet" to the visible network-adapter:

eg: 
on host a ip 192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0, 
on host b ip 192.168.0.11 netmask 255.255.255.0.

You should then be able to access the other vm via network.

Also check the presence of a "firewall" on the vms (iptables). It may block network requests.

Answer (score 0):

Are host A and host B are connected in a network?

If yes, create bridge between the corresponding VM to the host.